# Using CFHTTP with HTTPS domain in Railo

Tags: coldfusion, https, railo, cfhttp

I keep getting `Connection Failed` when trying to request data from a page that is on an `https://` domain. I did install the ssl cert using the built-in section of the railo admin at `https://[mydomain]/railo-context/admin/server.cfm?action=services.certificates` however I still get `Connection Failed`. How should I go forward with debugging this? I have confirmed that this server in particular does have access to the domain I am trying to request from.

Comment: You may need to install the entire certificate chain, not just the site cert. Try adding the intermediate cert, if there is one, and the root cert.

Comment: @JasonDean Thanks for the suggestion. I added both the root and the intermediate cert, but I'm still having the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being the permissions weren't setup properly on the machine. After we had the server administrator fix our permissions to access the `Railo-Tomcat Service Control`, the requests started working. I'm assuming he fixed some other permissions while he was in there.

Comment: Kevin, do you know exactly what permissions were fixed. I know it's been a while. I'm having the same issue. My environment is ubuntu 14.04 / tomcat7 / railo 4.2

Answer (score 2):

You probably need some additional certs installed as Jason has said. Take a close look at the cert and it's chain. Go to the cert issuers site and look for some documentation.

To troubleshoot you can add some logging to your jvm args. I think it's something like:

```
-Djavax.net.debug=all
```

The results are either in the OUT log or the server.log. This post on [SSL 3.0](http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2009/2/24/CF-SSL30-Authorize-net) has some debugging tips. It's possible that your cert needs to handshake at a lower security level than CF allows (SSL 2.0 instead of 3.0/TLS for instance) and that could cause this behavior - but it's more likely that you simply need an intermediate cert installed.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the `-Djavax.net.debug=all`, this ultimately lead to finding out that we had a user permissions problem with our server.